# restrictions of a function almost everywhere equal to zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f : R^2 \to R$ be a measurable function. Suppose that for all $x \in R$,  $f(x,\cdot)$ is equal to zero almost everywhere. Is $f$ equal to zero almost everywhere?

Comment: Fubini comes to mind...

Comment: Exactly. For any product of intervals $A\times B$, $$\iint_{A\times B}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy=\int_B\int_{A}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy = \int_{B} 0\,dy = 0.$$